Using bash shortcuts in kate(Vi mode)
I like to use the bash shortcuts on kate Vi mode and insert mode(vi mode).
For example, when I press ctrl+u to delete the start of the line.
Is there a way

To be pedantic, Ctrl+U deletes to the start of the line. Ctrl+K deletes from the cursor to the end of the line.

Ok. I know. But it doesn't work in Vi mode

Solved With this issue:
https://invent.kde.org/utilities/kate/-/issues/122
I realized that if I removed the Close and Uppercasce shortcuts, the problem would be solved.
Select Custom and Don't enter anything in the input field or enter another alternative.
Of course, only this worked for ctrl+w and ctrl+u.
But so I was just looking for these two.
This shortcuts work in insert mode.


Kate is Good!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
